# Jest saying @babel/preset-react missing when it is there

Tags: jestjs, babeljs

When I run jest I am seeing this error:

Add @babel/preset-react (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-preset-react) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.

But I have this

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    ["@babel/preset-react", { runtime: "automatic" }],
  ],
};
```

Comment: Can you share your `jest.config.js`?